# How can I send Snort Log Files to hadoop Mapreduce automatically?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, flume, logfile, snort

I want to send Snort Log Files to hadoop Mapreduce automatically, Is there specific tool I should use ?
Does Apache Flume perform this job ?

Comment: Yes Apache Flume will perform the required task and you can use Logstash (ELK) Elastic search for the same requirement...

Comment: What is the better one to transmit stream of large amount of data between snort and hadoop ?